# Xammp and VPN's, how to allow access

Tags: xampp

I have Xampp on a server and am able to access it from inside my local network, I have 3 vpns to other rooftops that can ping the server just fine, but can't get xampp to allow them to pull up a web page on the server outside the local network.

found this on the web, works for local but not the vpns:

```
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 x.x.x.0/8\
fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 x.x.0.0/16\
fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16
```

how do you allow access to a webpage through your vpns and not screw up security with 'Allow from all'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to whitelist all connections you will have to set up 3 rules.
If it works for the local network it should work for VPNs either. So i guess you have a problem by detecting the correct ips for the vpns.
They depend on which kind of VPN you are using:

1. If it is a End-to-End VPN you should know the VPN Net ip and subnet mask. You can look for it in the vpn adapters settings.
2. If it is a Site-to-End VPN there should be no problem as the clients are a part of the local network.
3. If it is a site-to-site VPN and there are no forwarding rules active you also wouldnt have a problem. Unless the ip addresses overlap.
   If you are working with forwarding it will be very hard to handle the different ip ranges. So consider using a simple vpn.

I hope i got your question right and it may help someone:)

Comment: It is a site to site, I ended up just making a webpage on our website that does everything I was trying to do in the VPN, plus now it can be accessed anywhere.